# Pause youtube video on youtube website using a parameter in url

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have a youtube video playing and I want the video to pause at the last slide. Is this possible? The video is playing using the URL http://youtube.googleapis.com. Is there a parameter I can set in the URL that will pause the video?